# Create tabular View by Spreading Data from JSON in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm very new to Snowflake and I am working on creating a view from the table that holds JSON data as follows :

```
"data": {
 "baseData": {
             "dom_url": "https://www.soccertables.com/european_tables",
             "event_id": "01b2722a-d8e6-4f67-95d0-8dd7ba088a4a",
             "event_utc_time": "2020-05-11 09:01:14.821",
             "ip_address": "125.238.134.96",
             "table_1": [
                {
                  "position": "1",
                  "team_name": "Liverpool",
                  "games_played": "29",
                  "games_won": "26",
                  "games_drawn": "2",
                  "games_lost": "1",
                  "goals_for": "75",
                  "goals_against": "35"
                  "points": "80"
                },
                {
                  "position": "2",
                  "team_name": "Man. City",
                  "games_played": "29",
                  "games_won": "20",
                  "games_drawn": "5",
                  "games_lost": "4",
                  "goals_for": "60",
                  "goals_against": "45"
                  "points": "65"
                },
                {
                  "position": "...",
                  "team_name": "...",
                  "games_played": "...",
                  "games_won": "...",
                  "games_drawn": "...",
                  "games_lost": "...",
                  "goals_for": "...",
                  "goals_against": "..."
                  "points": "..."
                }
           ],
   "unitID": "CN 8000",
   "ver": "1.0.0"
 },
 "baseType": "MatchData"
},
"dataName": "CN8000.Prod.MatchData",
"id": "18a89f9e-9620-4453-a546-23412025e7c0",
"tags": {
 "itrain.access.level1": "Private",
 "itrain.access.level2": "Kumar",
 "itrain.internal.deviceID": "",
 "itrain.internal.deviceName": "",
 "itrain.internal.encodeTime": "2022-03-23T07:41:19.000Z",
 "itrain.internal.sender": "Harish",
 "itrain.software.name": "",
 "itrain.software.partNumber": 0,
 "itrain.software.version": ""
},
"timestamp": "2021-02-25T07:32:31.000Z"
}
```

I want to extract the common values like dom_url, event_id, event_utc_time, ip_address along with **each team_name in a separate column** and the associated team details like position, games_played etc possibly in rows for each team name

E.g :

[image]

I've been trying Lateral flatten function but couldn't succeed so far

```
create or replace view AWSS3_PM.PUBLIC.PM_POWER_CN8000_V1(
    DOM_URL,
    EVENT_ID,
    EVENT_UTC_TIME,
    IP_ADDRESS,
    TIMESTAMP,
    POSITION,
    GAMES_PLAYED,
    GAMES_WON,
    GAMES_LOST,
    GAMES_DRAWN
) as
select c1:data:baseData:dom_url dom_url, 
       c1:data:baseData:event_id event_id,
       c1:data:baseData:event_utc_time event_utc_time,
       c1:data:baseData:ip_address ip_address,
       c1:timestamp timestamp,
       value:position TeamPosition, 
       value:games_played gamesPlayed, 
       value:games_won wins , 
       value:games_lost defeats,
       value:games_drawn draws
from pm_power, lateral flatten(input => c1:data:baseData:table_1);
```

Any help would be really grateful

Thanks,
Harish

Answer (score 1):

#For the table Portion in JSON it would need flattening and transpose, example below -

## Sample table -

```
select * from test_json;

+--------------------------------+
| TAB_VAL                        |
|--------------------------------|
| {                              |
|   "table_1": [                 |
|     {                          |
|       "games_drawn": "2",      |
|       "games_lost": "1",       |
|       "games_played": "29",    |
|       "games_won": "26",       |
|       "goals_against": "35",   |
|       "goals_for": "75",       |
|       "points": "80",          |
|       "position": "1",         |
|       "team_name": "Liverpool" |
|     },                         |
|     {                          |
|       "games_drawn": "5",      |
|       "games_lost": "4",       |
|       "games_played": "29",    |
|       "games_won": "20",       |
|       "goals_against": "45",   |
|       "goals_for": "60",       |
|       "points": "65",          |
|       "position": "2",         |
|       "team_name": "Man. City" |
|     }                          |
|   ]                            |
| }                              |
+--------------------------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.285s
```

## Perform transpose after flattening JSON

```
select * from (
    select figures,stats,team_name 
    from (
        select
            f.value:"games_drawn"::number as games_drawn,
            f.value:"games_lost"::number as games_lost,
            f.value:"games_played"::number as games_played,
            f.value:"games_won"::number as games_won,
            f.value:"goals_against"::number as goals_against,
            f.value:"goals_for"::number as goals_for,
            f.value:"points"::number as points,
            f.value:"position"::number as position,
            f.value:"team_name"::String as team_name
        from
            TEST_JSON, table(flatten(input=>tab_val:table_1, mode=>'ARRAY')) as f
        ) flt
        unpivot (figures for stats in(games_drawn, games_lost, games_played, games_won, goals_against, goals_for, points,position))
) up
pivot (min(up.figures) for up.team_name in ('Liverpool','Man. City'));
```

```
+---------------+-------------+-------------+
| STATS         | 'Liverpool' | 'Man. City' |
|---------------+-------------+-------------|
| GAMES_DRAWN   |           2 |           5 |
| GAMES_LOST    |           1 |           4 |
| GAMES_PLAYED  |          29 |          29 |
| GAMES_WON     |          26 |          20 |
| GOALS_AGAINST |          35 |          45 |
| GOALS_FOR     |          75 |          60 |
| POINTS        |          80 |          65 |
| POSITION      |           1 |           2 |
+---------------+-------------+-------------+
8 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.293s
```

Comment: it might seem offensive to have edit your answer, but the console output brings no contextual value to the answer, and severely impacts the readability of the answer, and there is so much system font, that is not all equal, and the prompt often pushes the valuable SQL off to the right.

Comment: Thanks a lot pankaj and @simeonPilgrim. A small query, I dont want to limit with just two team_names, I would like to flatten and pivot for all teams, could you please shed some light on how to do that. Also, I want to fetch data outside table_1 as well.